# Регулярное выражение ЧПУ

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mod-rewrite

Добрый день.

Имеется ссылка `http://site.ru/forum.php?page=lonely` которую мы преобразуем в `http://site.ru/forum/lonely` следующим образом:

```
RewriteRule ^forum[/]([a-z0-9]+)?$ forum.php?page=$1 [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum.php$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ACCESS_ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteRule ^forum.php$ forum/ [L,R=301]
```

Как переделать данное регулярное выражение, чтобы работала ссылка такого вида:

```
http://site.ru/forum/lonely?param=p1
```

или

```
http://site.ru/forum/lonely&param=p1
```

Comment: А какой должна быть итоговая ссылка? Куда девать p1?

Comment: p1 это не статичная GET переменная. Впоследствии она изымается из URL через массив $_GET['param']. Итоговая ссылка может быть или такой: http://site.ru/forum/lonely или такой: http://site.ru/forum/lonely?param=p1. Обе ссылки должны быть рабочими. Во второй ссылке, мы просто добавляем дополнительный GET параметр, чтобы затем использовать его в своём коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет что-то вроде

```
RewriteRule ^forum[/]([a-z0-9]*)([?&](.*))?$ forum.php?page=$1&$3 [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
...
```

То есть за вашим регулярным выражением (чуть подправленым) следует наобязательная часть, первый символ которой или ? или &, а затем идет все что угодно до конца строки. Вот это все, что угодно, добавляется в качестве GET-параметров после page=$1. Увы, прямо сейчас проверить не могу, но должно работать.

**Обновление**. Итоговая строка:

```
RewriteRule ^forum[/]([a-z0-9]*)(&(.*))?$ forum.php?page=$1&$3%{QUERY_STRING} [L,E=ACCESS_ALLOWED:1]
```

Comment: Да. Довольно неплохой вариант. Работает с ссылкой вида http://site.ru/forum/lonely&param=p1. Но есть небольшой нюанс. Если вместо "&" вписать в эту ссылку "?", то GET параметры не передаются. Можно ли это поправить? Хотя я вижу что в условии стоит [?&]. Может это потому, что у нас уже есть один вопросительный знак в ссылке?

Comment: Увы, мне не на чем сейчас проверить, а умозрительно сходу я проблемы не вижу. Вопрос в любом случае не должен передаваться, у меня стоит после page=$1 следующая строка: &$3. То есть даже, если "?", а не "&" в исходном URL, я в любом случае ставлю "&", а затем все, что идет после вопроса (то есть его я не включаю). В общем, если никто в ближайшее время не поправит, я вечером смогу отладить и исправить ответ.

Comment: С помощью гугла нашел замечательную вещь http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, которая помогла разобраться. В URL для rewriting'а не включаются GET-параметры, поэтому я просто явно их добавляю в итоговый URL.

Comment: Благодарю тебя Друг за потраченное время и помощь.